# What is the subsequence of largest points so far called?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

Given a sequence $\{x_n\}$, is there a name for the subsequence of largest-points-so-far, that is, $\{x_{n_k} : x_{n_k} > x_i\text{ for all }i<n_k\}$?

Answer (score 0):

I think an official term would be "cumulative maximums".

Sometimes I've seen these called the "champions" of the sequence.

Comment: The term that I’ve seen most often is *left-to-right maxima*. I’ve seen at least one paper that uses the term *outstanding elements*. I’d strongly recommend defining whatever term one uses.

Comment: I swear I've seen an entry in the OEIS refer to these as "high water marks", but I have no idea which sequence it was.